# How can I use an SVG file as a node background in Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've found in the docs that I can use image as a background for the nodes using GSS [NodeStyle directive properties](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph-lab/style-script/gss-nodestyle-directive). Code for using images is simple to understand `image-url: "https://download.memgraph.com/asset/images/memgraph-logo.png"` but I'd like to use SVG file as background. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research on this topic. I've found an [issue in Orb GitHub repository](https://github.com/memgraph/orb/issues/59) that might be helpful. It seems that the easiest way is to convert image to DataURI and then use that in the GSS.
There are tools online to give you DataURI from an image, it is a text which contains full image info.

Other method is [described in Memgraph documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/how-to-guides/font-awesome-for-node-images) and it comes down to converting SVG file to PNG. The issue that I see with this approach is that you need connection to some service where you've uploaded the image.

I want to have all my resources in one place so I've played around with idea of copying PNG files into Docker image for Memgraph Platform. You can reference the image files if you copy them to `/lab/dist-frontend/assets/img` and then reference them in GSS code with `image-url: "http://localhost:3000/assets/img/image-nampe.png".`